# How to solve this without L'Hopital?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x-2)}{x^2+x-6}$$ is not defined at $x=2$ and $x=-3$, how can I solve this without using de l'Hôpital's theorem to be defined continuous at $x=2$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin x\sim x$ then $\sin (x-2) \sim x-2$, which implies that $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{\sin (x-2)}{(x-2) (x+3)}=\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{1}{x+3}=\frac{1}{5}, $$so if you define $f(2) =1/5$ then its continuous in that point. For $x=-3$ you cannot extens continuously the function since the limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: I would not agree with you . (I am *not* an expert ) . Consider $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac 1{x^2}-\frac 1{\sin^2 x}\right)$$ We can see that the statement $\sin x\sim x$ obviously fails. I would go with the following way : $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac {\sin (x-2)}{x-2}\cdot \lim_{x\to 2}\frac 1{x+3}=\frac 15$$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, thats what $\sin x\sim x$, which is obviusly true.  Your "counterxample" Is of the form $\infty-\infty$ not $0/0$, thats why the reasoning fails.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Consider $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2x}$$

Comment: Yes, it is a good justification. Again you are misunderstanding $\sin x-x\to 0$ with $\sin x/x\to 1$.

Comment: @lonestudent this explanation is fine. Terse, but correct (except for the final statement about the limit being $-\infty$… the limit as $x\to-3$ does not exist). The notation “$f(x)\sim\phi(x)$ (as $x\to a$)” means by definition $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{\phi(x)}=1$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo But, what I was talking about here was the *swapping/replacing* of 
$\sin (x-2)$  and $x-2$ .  I was not referring to the conventional definition.

Comment: @lonestudent if you mean the first equality, then that is completely justified by the properties of limits (which you mentioned as well in your first comment). Guillermo did say “…, which implies that…” so, although the fully detailed explanation was not given (i.e that one extra step you mentioned), what is written is still correct. But, I would agree that it is somewhat terse (atleast for someone who is working through limits initially).